# Is it ever a good idea to use the design pattern name in the implementing classes?

Tags: design-patterns, naming

Recently I came across a moderately large python codebase with lots of `MyClassAbstractFactory`, `MyClassManager`, `MyClassProxy`, `MyClassAdapter` etc. classes.

While on the one hand those names pointed me to research and learn the corresponding patterns, they were not very descriptive of what the class **does**.

Also, they seem to fall within the forbidden list of words in programming: `variable`, `process_available_information`, `data`, `amount`, `compute`: overly broad names, that don't tell us anything about the function **when used by themselves**.

*So should there be `CommunicationManager` or rather `PortListener`? Or maybe I do not understand the problem at all...?*

Comment: if you are familiar with what the pattern does then the pattern name is a decent description, however *just* the pattern name is a bad idea, it's better to have a MyClassFactory, a FooAdapter, etc.

Comment: Edited the question to indicate that the classes were not called just "AbstractFactory", but some descriptive words were there too.

Comment: ...did they seriously call it a `Fctory` instead of a `Factory`, or is that just a typo?

Comment: @Izkata, lol, my bad. However, there were Adaptor and Adapter!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

- `AbstractFactory` is indeed a poor choice for a name. **There is no way to know *what* is created by this factory**, and when you'll look for an entity which creates `Animal`s, you'll never find the corresponding factory by name.
- `AnimalAbstractFactory` is not a wise choice neither, since in most languages, it would be **redundant** with the `abstract` keyword in the signature.

  This being said, there are several good reasons, highlighted by the comments, to actually include `Abstract` in the name: not only there are several contexts where you don't have the full signature, but just the name, but also, keeping `AnimalFactory` for an interface may be a wise choice (unless, unfortunately, the convention of the language/framework is to prefix interfaces with `I`).
- `AnimalCreationUtility` would also be a bad choice: **if it's a factory**, make things easier for people who will read code, and **call it a factory**.
- `abstract AnimalFactory` is ok. It doesn't have redundancy, and is clear that it *is* an *abstract* factory which delegates the creation of animals to its children.

So yes, including the name of the design pattern is a good idea, but it should be only a part of the name, and shouldn't be redundant with the other parts of the signature.

Comment: Why is this better than writing a comment in a prominent place "In this module, we implement MVC. Reasons: ... Models:... Views:... Controllers:... Structure map:... API:... ".

Comment: @Vorac: Having a clear name is *always* better than relying on comments.

Comment: @Vorac sooner or later someone will add a new class without updating that prominent comment (or even knowing about its existence). While it's much harder to overlook a naming convention consistently used across the entire app.

Comment: While you are browsing through your project solution, will you open each class file to find what it does? No. That is why it's always a better idea to have descriptive name classes/files.

Comment: I would like to kindly disagree with the second point: I think that AnimalAbstractFactory is a good choice, because even though it is redundant in the class declaration, it would be very helpful in the child class declaration: LionFactory extends AnimalAbstractFactory which, I think, is a nice piece of information.

Comment: @Igor: indeed, there are valid reasons to include `Abstract` in the name. Another reason is the one mentioned by @matrix: if you're in front of a list of files, you don't know whether they contain an abstract class or a concrete implementation.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer using `AbstractAnimalFactory`, and then keep `AnimalFactory` in reserve in case I need an *interface*. IMO developing against an interface is generally better, and if you're doing that then you want the commonly-appearing classes to be pleasing to read. (In other words, *not* `IAnimalFactory`.)

Answer (score 11):

Depends on the specific example. The Builder pattern is almost always best served by naming your class *Builder, while a Singleton doesn't usually need to be named as such.

If you don't put the pattern name in your class name, and maybe even if you do, you should generally put a comment in the class which explains that it implements a specific pattern.

Comment: Consistency is crucial here, because once only *some* factories are called `...Factory`, it becomes quite a mental bump to realize a class is a factory if its naming breaks that convention.

Answer (score 10):

The whole point of using pattern names in classes is to make it easy to understand what the class does. If you name the class AnimalFactory it's obvious that the class creates Animal instances. If the name of your class includes a name of a pattern and it does not describe what it does you've either chosen a wrong pattern or implemented it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can work really well. For example:

```
// Command for retrying card entry with CVN.
public class RetryCardEntryWithCVNCommand { ... }

// Query for getting expired accounts
public class GetExpiredAccountsQuery { ... }

// Decorator for logging exception. Implies that it's an additional 
//mechanism for logging exceptions.
public class LogExceptionToDbDecorator { ... }

// Factory for creating account filters
public class AccountFilterFactory { ... }
```

Comment: how does this answer the question asked? Per my reading, your "examples" only show useless [duplication](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dry) of class names and code comments

Comment: Comments are to justify purpose of each class in case class name is not apparent to some. By looking at these I instantly know that I have command that does something, query that returns data, decorator that adds additional behaviour to existing exception logging mechanism and a factory that creates account filters. In my opinion the more descriptive you are with your class names, the easier it becomes for others to read your code. If you are using a design pattern, then say so - at the end of the day the whole purpose of having design patterns is to make it easier for others to read your code